# Cauchy Criterion for series sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The Cauchy Criterion for a series can be defined:

**Theorem**: *A series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n\ge m \gt N$ we have $|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} a_k|< \epsilon$.*

My question is why does the sum start at *m+1* and not at *m*, shouldn't the difference between the *m*th and *n*th term include the *m*th term?

Comment: Yes,this should be start from $m$, but one might make $\sum_{k=m+1}^ma_k=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ , $S_m=\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k$ . So the difference is $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}a_k$.

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't immediately obvious to me. Is there a general rule for how the index of summation changes with operations on summations?

Comment: Not really. But the way, if you are confused with the sigma you can try to write the sum as $a_1+a_2+...+a_n$, sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\geq m>N$ an consider the partials sums $S_n$ and $S_m$ so, by Cauchy criterion we have
$$
|S_n-S_m|=|\sum_{k=m+1}^na_k|
$$